# store one array value in other array of object in php

Tags: php, arrays, object, array-merge

I have 2 arrays Like below

```
$array1 =  Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [CUSTOMERTRXLINEID] => 2683959
                [LINETYPE] => LINE
                [LINEAMOUNT] => 153000
                [TAXAMOUNT] => 0
                [INVOICEAMOUNT] => 153020
                [CREDITEDAMOUNT] => 
                [ORIGINALLINEAMOUNT] => 153000
                [DESCRIPTION] => Silver Office Package Property#W 101,from 11-02-2018 to 10-02-2019 Area52.5
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [CUSTOMERTRXLINEID] => 2683960
                [LINETYPE] => LINE
                [LINEAMOUNT] => 10
                [TAXAMOUNT] => 0
                [INVOICEAMOUNT] => 153020
                [CREDITEDAMOUNT] => 
                [ORIGINALLINEAMOUNT] => 10
                [DESCRIPTION] => Knowledge Fees (As per Government of Dubai - Law(4) 2005
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [CUSTOMERTRXLINEID] => 2683961
                [LINETYPE] => LINE
                [LINEAMOUNT] => 10
                [TAXAMOUNT] => 0
                [INVOICEAMOUNT] => 153020
                [CREDITEDAMOUNT] => 
                [ORIGINALLINEAMOUNT] => 10
                [DESCRIPTION] => Innovation Fees (As per Government of Dubai - Law(20) 2015)
            )
    )
```

and second array as

```
$array2 = Array
(
    [0] => 68850.00
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 10
)
```

I want to create one more entry in every object of first array as `[APPROVEDAMT] =>` and store 2nd array values to it. I want resulting array to look like below

```
$result_array =  Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [CUSTOMERTRXLINEID] => 2683959
                [LINETYPE] => LINE
                [LINEAMOUNT] => 153000
                [TAXAMOUNT] => 0
                [INVOICEAMOUNT] => 153020
                [CREDITEDAMOUNT] => 
                [ORIGINALLINEAMOUNT] => 153000
                [DESCRIPTION] => Silver Office Package Property#W 101,from 11-02-2018 to 10-02-2019 Area52.5
                [APPROVEDAMT] => 68850.00
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [CUSTOMERTRXLINEID] => 2683960
                [LINETYPE] => LINE
                [LINEAMOUNT] => 10
                [TAXAMOUNT] => 0
                [INVOICEAMOUNT] => 153020
                [CREDITEDAMOUNT] => 
                [ORIGINALLINEAMOUNT] => 10
                [DESCRIPTION] => Knowledge Fees (As per Government of Dubai - Law(4) 2005
                [APPROVEDAMT] => 10
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [CUSTOMERTRXLINEID] => 2683961
                [LINETYPE] => LINE
                [LINEAMOUNT] => 10
                [TAXAMOUNT] => 0
                [INVOICEAMOUNT] => 153020
                [CREDITEDAMOUNT] => 
                [ORIGINALLINEAMOUNT] => 10
                [DESCRIPTION] => Innovation Fees (As per Government of Dubai - Law(20) 2015)
                [APPROVEDAMT] => 10
            )
    )
```

This is what i tried.

```
$total_line_items=$formData['totallineitem']->value;
        $decode_array = json_decode($formData['invoice']->value);
        $formArray = array($formData);
        $ap_array = [];
        for($x=0; $x<$total_line_items; $x++){
            $ap_array[] = $formArray[0]['approve_amount_'.$x]->value;
        }
        for($i=0; $i<$total_line_items;$i++)
        {
            $data_value=$formData['data'.$i]->value;
            $approved_amt=$formData['approve_amount_'.$i]->value;
            if($data_value)
            {
                foreach($decode_array->LINEDETAILS as $array){
                    $array->APPROVEDAMT = $ap_array[$i];
                    print_r($array->APPROVEDAMT);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Usual foreach does the job. What have you tried?.

Comment: I tried foreach also for n all. but the indexing and storing is not happening properly

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: $total_line_items=$formData['totallineitem']->value;
  $decode_array = json_decode($formData['invoice']->value);
  $formArray = array($formData);
  $ap_array = [];
  for($x=0; $x<$total_line_items; $x++){
   $ap_array[] = $formArray[0]['approve_amount_'.$x]->value;
  }
  for($i=0; $i<$total_line_items;$i++)
  {
   $data_value=$formData['data'.$i]->value;
   $approved_amt=$formData['approve_amount_'.$i]->value;
   if($data_value)
   {
    foreach($decode_array->LINEDETAILS as $array){
     $array->APPROVEDAMT = $ap_array[$i];
     print_r($array->APPROVEDAMT);
    }
   }
  }

Comment: Put it in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $array1[$key]['APPROVEDAMT'] = $array2[$key];
}
```

it will loop first array and add a new index with the second array value. Hope that helps

Comment: Please consider my answer if that helped you